# want slowly import to mysql with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: java, mysql, database, innodb

I am importing data from textfiles into mysql  using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

If I throw all data at once to the mysql master I cause pretty **much replication drift** between master and slave. Other processes which change data on master will need to wait quite a bit to see their changes getting replicated to the slaves.

I would not mind, if my import takes longer.

How can I slow down LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, mean forcing it to commit and wait a few seconds after each 1000 lines from the import file?

I am using mysql-connector-java 5.1.6

*data_files* in following code snippet  is a map files and corresponding tablesnames.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

....
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data_files.entrySet()) {

                    String batchStmt = String
                            .format("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \"%s\" IGNORE INTO TABLE %s IGNORE 1 LINES",
                                    entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());

                    stmt.addBatch(batchStmt);
                }
                stmt.executeBatch();
                connection.commit();
```

Comment: Set a counter for however many loops you want (1000) then `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` or a few, then reset the counter.

Comment: I do not want to sleep just between the loading of the 6 files. Because even one file is pretty big, I want to sleep even after reading 1000 lines from one file. And i do not want to convert one big file to several small ones.

Comment: You can't really select to load only certain lines in a file: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21944/how-do-i-import-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file-into-mysql . Splitting the files up is probably your best bet. Note that you want to execute and commit inside your loop, or else the entire job will just wait and commit at the end anyway.